# Schedule API callback with specified input to my server

Tags: node.js, amazon-ec2, lambda, callback, scheduled-tasks

I've a Nodejs server running on Amazon EC2 cloud under ELB which serves REST APIs to android and web clients. I want to achieve following:

- Client executes /book API with callback time and booking_id as input.
- Node server registers callback to it's /serve API with booking_id as input at *callback time specified in /book request*

Example: 
1. Client A calls /book API with input 
 `{ 
 "booking_id": 1234, 
 "callback_at" :"Oct 4, 5 pm" 
}`
(The actual callback_at value will be an ISO timestamp.)
 
2. NodeJS server under ELB registers callback to /serve API with some scheduler like AWS Lambda at Oct 4, 5pm and input as booking_id 1234.
I cannot use OS based or other system specific scheduler which will fail if that instance of server under ELB goes down. It has to be a scale-able solution.
 Therefore, it must be some external scheduler service. 
So far I've found AWS Lambda as possible solution to achieve this. Are there better/free alternatives for scheduling callback?
 Is there a better approach to fulfil this requirement?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Lambda seems the way to go in an AWS infrastructure for scheduled tasks.

Answer (score 0):

have a look at node-schedule:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-schedule

Comment: Please provide context for the link you are sharing. Although the link you shared may indeed be very helpful, it is advisable to rather capture the key aspects of the shared article that respond to the question. 
This way, even if the link is removed your answer will still be relevant and helpful.

Comment: @Andy thanks but as mentioned in description, this will be applicable for single instance of Node server. So if that single instance goes down, scheduled job will be lost.